# crontab not working in kohana freamwork

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm using crontab to call my function.
but it is not working.

My function is working browser as well as in postman too.

====> MY FUNCTION

```
public function action_dateNotification() {


          $sql = "INSERT INTO testcrown(name) VALUES('nitin')";
            DB::query(Database::INSERT, $sql)->execute();
            echo "inserted";

}
```

below url is working in browser and postman. When we invoke this url entry get save into database.

http://www.nkg.com/index.php/api/firebasenotification/dateNotification

I have set above url in crontab -e file

1 * * * * php index.php --uri=controller/api/firebasenotification/dateNotification

My project kohana version 3.1.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Kohana Task](https://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/minion/tasks) or:

```
1 * * * * wget http://example.com/controller/api/firebasenotification/dateNotification
```